# iphone: How do I get the location of a touch down event?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have an empty View-Based app.  I'd like to do something with the x,y coordinates of every touch down on the screen.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Override the

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

function (from the NSRespondrer class).  You can override it from your view class.  The 'touches' variable hold a set of 'UITouch' instances that you can query for the location in the view.