# How can you add a UIGestureRecognizer to a UIBarButtonItem as in the common undo/redo UIPopoverController scheme on iPad apps?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uibarbuttonitem, undo-redo, uigesturerecognizer

**Problem**

In my iPad app, I cannot attach a popover to a button bar item *only* after press-and-hold events.  But this seems to be standard for undo/redo.  How do other apps do this?

**Background**

I have an undo button (UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo) in the toolbar of my UIKit (iPad) app.  When I press the undo button, it fires it's action which is undo:, and that executes correctly.

However, the "standard UE convention" for undo/redo on iPad is that pressing undo executes an undo but *pressing and holding* the button reveals a popover controller where the user selected either "undo" or "redo" until the controller is dismissed.

The normal way to attach a popover controller is with presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:, and I can configure this easily enough.  To get this to show only after press-and-hold we have to set a view to respond to "long press" gesture events as in this snippet:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressOnUndoGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
       initWithTarget:self 
               action:@selector(handleLongPressOnUndoGesture:)];
//Broken because there is no customView in a UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo item
[self.undoButtonItem.customView addGestureRecognizer:longPressOnUndoGesture];
[longPressOnUndoGesture release];
```

With this, after a press-and-hold on the view the method handleLongPressOnUndoGesture: will get called, and within this method I will configure and display the popover for undo/redo.  So far, so good.

The problem with this is that there *is no view* to attach to.  self.undoButtonItem is a UIButtonBarItem, not a view.

**Possible solutions**

1) [The ideal] *Attach the gesture recognizer to the button bar item*.  It is possible to attach a gesture recognizer to a view, but UIButtonBarItem is not a view.  It does have a property for .customView, but that property is nil when the buttonbaritem is  a standard system type (in this case it is).

2) *Use another view*.  I could use the UIToolbar but that would require some weird hit-testing and be an all around hack, if even possible in the first place.  There is no other alternative view to use that I can think of.

3) *Use the customView property*.  Standard types like UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo have no customView (it is nil).  Setting the customView will erase the standard contents which it needs to have.  This would amount to re-implementing all the look and function of UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo, again if even possible to do.

**Question**

How can I attach a gesture recognizer to this "button"?  More specifically, how can I implement the standard press-and-hold-to-show-redo-popover in an iPad app?

Ideas?  Thank you very much, especially if someone actually has this working in their app (I'm thinking of you, omni) and wants to share...

Answer (score 25):

***Note: this no longer works as of iOS 11***

In lieu of that mess with trying to find the UIBarButtonItem's view in the toolbar's subview list, you can also try this, once the item is added to the toolbar:

```
[barButtonItem valueForKey:@"view"];
```

This uses the Key-Value Coding framework to access the UIBarButtonItem's private _view variable, where it keeps the view it created.

Granted, I don't know where this falls in terms of Apple's private API thing (this is public method used to access a private variable of a public class - not like accessing private frameworks to make fancy Apple-only effects or anything), but it does work, and rather painlessly.

Comment: Great answer +1, the API/legality question looms large. Hmmmm

Comment: This is the most simple and most reliable way to access the view. In the end, all the other methods suggested here essentially access the same variable, so they are not any more "legal" than this one - only more difficult to detect. Has anyone tried to submit an app that uses this "valueForKey" method?

Comment: This is simpler and _probably_ more future-proof. One of the big risks of using the private API (aside from rejection) is that your code may break in the future. Wrapping this code in `if ([[sortmodeBarButtonItem valueForKey:@"view"] respondsToSelector:@selector(addGestureRecognizer:)])` would make it even more robust.

Comment: This works great.  Just needed to use it in viewDidAppear as it returns nil if called earlier.  Has anyone used this technique and successfully launched their app?

Comment: Here's a UIBarButtonItem subclass in Objective-C that lets you set a target and action for a long press, so you don't need to put that mess in your view controller. It sends off the action immediately as soon as the long press triggers (not on touches ended), and it conveniently won't fire if the bar button item is disabled: https://pastebin.com/0a6DvNFM

Comment: Since IOS11 `[barButtonItem valueForKey:@"view"]` will return nil. The only solution seems to be to implement a custom view. See also the answer of laxman khanal.

Answer (score 13):

This is an old question, but it still comes up in google searches, and all of the other answers are overly complicated.

I have a buttonbar, with buttonbar items, that call an action:forEvent: method when pressed.

In that method, add these lines:

```
bool longpress=NO;
UITouch *touch=[[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
if(touch.tapCount==0) longpress=YES;
```

If it was a single tap, tapCount is one. If it was a double tap, tapCount is two. If it's a long press, tapCount is zero.

Comment: How do you make a UIBarButtonItem call a action:forEvent: method? Doesn't it only call an action:sender: method?

Comment: Ah, I didn't find this documented anywhere, but I just set the action of a UIBarButtonItem to myMethod:forEvent: and it worked, passing an event object to my method. Unfortunately, the method isn't called until I release my tap, so although I can check the tapCount to see if a long press was completed, I can't perform an action at the moment a tap turns into a long press.

Comment: utopian deserves 10+ stars. While after 5+ years of iPhone development I (again!) ran into this question, I tried the **valueForKey** and **UILongPressGestureRecognizer** approach which obviously no longer works on iOS 8 but the **action:forEvent** approach still works. Great! Thanks! Just a bit of clarification: you need to change the action method to **-(IBAction)button_hit:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event { ... }** and use **...@selector(button_hit:forEvent:)** to add the target event or connect from XCode the usual way.

Comment: This is definitely the best solution and also works on iOS8.3

Comment: Works greats. Note though that I think this is slightly difference from UILongPressGestureRecognizer in that it first on touch up AFTER the long press FYI.

Answer (score 9):

Option 1 is indeed possible. Unfortunately it's a painful thing to find the UIView that the UIBarButtonItem creates. Here's how I found it:

```
[[[myToolbar subviews] objectAtIndex:[[myToolbar items] indexOfObject:myBarButton]] addGestureRecognizer:myGesture];
```

This is more difficult than it ought to be, but this is clearly designed to stop people from fooling around with the buttons look and feel.

Note that Fixed/Flexible spaces are **not** counted as views!

In order to handle spaces you must have some way of detecting them, and sadly the SDK simply has no easy way to do this. There are solutions and here are a few of them:

1) Set the UIBarButtonItem's tag value to it's index from left to right on the toolbar. This requires too much manual work to keep it in sync IMO.

2) Set any spaces' enabled property to NO. Then use this code snippet to set the tag values for you:

```
NSUInteger index = 0;
for (UIBarButtonItem *anItem in [myToolbar items]) {
    if (anItem.enabled) {
        // For enabled items set a tag.
        anItem.tag = index;
        index ++;
    }
}

// Tag is now equal to subview index.
[[[myToolbar subviews] objectAtIndex:myButton.tag] addGestureRecognizer:myGesture];
```

Of course this has a potential pitfall if you disable a button for some other reason.

3) Manually code the toolbar and handle the indexes yourself. As you'll be building the UIBarButtonItem's yourself, so you'll know in advance what index they'll be in the subviews. You could extend this idea to collecting up the UIView's in advance for later use, if necessary.

Comment: I ran into an odd problem with this: the system was reordering my toolbar subviews, for no reason that I could see. I resorted to (effectively) sorting the subviews by their frame.origin.x. Also, the system was inserting a UIView into the toolbar subviews with a negative x & y. I swear it wasn't me.... (FWIW, this was with the 4.3 SDK.)

Comment: Great answer -- thanks, @v01d. I used this to derive a `UIToolbar (Gesture)` category to encapsulate this (see my answer here somewhere). Note, you do have to re-add gesture recognizers every time you assign to `toolbar.items` or use `[toolbar setItems]`, as the underlying UIViews appear to get recreated each time.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of groping around for a subview you can create the button on your own and add a button bar item with a custom view. Then you hook up the GR to your custom button.

Answer (score 5):

While this question is now over a year old, this is still a pretty annoying problem. I've submitted a bug report to Apple (**rdar://9982911**) and I suggest that anybody else who feels the same duplicate it.

Answer (score 3):

You also can simply do this...

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPress:")
navigationController?.toolbar.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

func longPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
let location = sender.locationInView(navigationController?.toolbar)
println(location)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Until iOS 11, `let barbuttonView = barButton.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView` will give us the reference to the view for barButton in which we can easily add gestures, but in iOS 11 the things are quite different, the above line of code will end up with **nil** so adding tap gesture to the view for key "view" is meaningless.

No worries we can still add tap gestures to the UIBarItems, since it have a property customView. What we can do is create a button with height & width 24 pt(according to Apple Human Interface Guidelines) and then assign the custom view as the newly created button. The below code will help you perform one action for single tap and another for tapping bar button 5 times.

**NOTE** For this purpose you must already have a reference to the barbuttonitem.

```
func setupTapGestureForSettingsButton() {
      let multiTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
      multiTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 5
      multiTapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
      multiTapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeTVC.askForPassword))
      let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeSettings(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
      let image = UIImage(named: "test_image")withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
      button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
      button.tintColor = ColorConstant.Palette.Blue
      settingButton.customView = button
      settingButton.customView?.addGestureRecognizer(multiTapGesture)          
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried something similar to what Ben suggested.  I created a custom view with a UIButton and used that as the customView for the UIBarButtonItem.  There were a couple of things I didn't like about this approach:

- The button needed to be styled to not stick out like a sore thumb on the UIToolBar
- With a UILongPressGestureRecognizer I didn't seem to get the click event for "Touch up Inside"  (This could/is most likely be programing error on my part.)

Instead I settled for something hackish at best but it works for me.  I'm used XCode 4.2 and I'm using ARC in the code below.  I created a new UIViewController subclass called CustomBarButtonItemView.  In the CustomBarButtonItemView.xib file I created a UIToolBar and added a single UIBarButtonItem to the toolbar.  I then shrunk the toolbar to almost the width of the button.  I then connected the File's Owner view property to the UIToolBar.

[image: Interface Builder view of CustomBarButtonViewController]

Then in my ViewController's viewDidLoad: message I created two UIGestureRecognizers.  The first was a UILongPressGestureRecognizer for the click-and-hold and second was UITapGestureRecognizer.  I can't seem to properly get the action for the UIBarButtonItem in the view so I fake it with the UITapGestureRecognizer.  The UIBarButtonItem does show itself as being clicked and the UITapGestureRecognizer takes care of the action just as if the action and target for the UIBarButtonItem was set.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestured)];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];

    CustomBarButtomItemView* customBarButtonViewController = [[CustomBarButtomItemView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomBarButtonItemView" bundle:nil];

    self.barButtonItem.customView = customBarButtonViewController.view;

    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;

    [self.barButtonItem.customView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    [self.barButtonItem.customView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];        

}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
};
-(void)longPressGestured{
    NSLog(@"Long Press Gestured");
}
```

Now when a single click occurs in the ViewController's barButtonItem (Connected via the xib file) the tap gesture calls the buttonPressed: message.  If the button is held down longPressGestured is fired.

For changing the appearance of the UIBarButton I'd suggest making a property for CustomBarButtonItemView to allow access to the Custom BarButton and store it in the ViewController class.  When the longPressGestured message is sent you can change the system icon of the button.

One gotcha I've found is the customview property takes the view as is.  If you alter the custom UIBarButtonitem from the CustomBarButtonItemView.xib to change the label to **@"really long string"** for example the button will resize itself but only the left most part of the button shown is in the view being watched by the UIGestuerRecognizer instances.

Answer (score 2):

I tried @voi1d's solution, which worked great until I changed the title of the button that I had added a long press gesture to. Changing the title appears to create a new UIView for the button that replaces the original, thus causing the added gesture to stop working as soon as a change is made to the button (which happens frequently in my app).

My solution was to subclass UIToolbar and override the `addSubview:` method. I also created a property that holds the pointer to the target of my gesture. Here's the exact code:

```
- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view {
    // This method is overridden in order to add a long-press gesture recognizer
    // to a UIBarButtonItem. Apple makes this way too difficult, but I am clever!
    [super addSubview:view];
    // NOTE - this depends the button of interest being 150 pixels across (I know...)
    if (view.frame.size.width == 150) {
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:targetOfGestureRecognizers 
                                                                                                action:@selector(showChapterMenu:)];
        [view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    }
}
```

In my particular situation, the button I'm interested in is 150 pixels across (and it's the only button that is), so that's the test I use. It's probably not the safest test, but it works for me. Obviously you'd have to come up with your own test and supply your own gesture and selector.

The benefit of doing it this way is that any time my UIBarButtonItem changes (and thus creates a new view), my custom gesture gets attached, so it always works!

Comment: I like this, as my UIBarButtonItem was changing randomly and often, for no apparent reason. However, it can be improved (made less wooly) by combining this approach with the `[barButtonItem valueForKey:@"view"];` approach from above. This gives you a definite reference to the view that belongs to the bar button item. Just compare the view being added to the toolbar with the one that the barButtonItem reports belongs to it. Rock solid!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I spent a night banging my head against the wall trying to find an acceptable solution. I didn't want to use the customView property because would get rid of all of the built in functionality like button tint, disabled tint, and the long press would be subjected to such a small hit box while UIBarButtonItems spread their hit box out quite a ways. I came up with this solution that I think works really well and is only a slight pain to implement.

In my case, the first 2 buttons on my bar would go to the same place if long pressed, so I just needed to detect that a press happened before a certain X point. I added the long press gesture recognizer to the UIToolbar (also works if you add it to a UINavigationBar) and then added an extra UIBarButtonItem that's 1 pixel wide right after the 2nd button. When the view loads, I add a UIView that's a single pixel wide to that UIBarButtonItem as it's customView. Now, I can test the point where the long press happened and then see if it's X is less than the X of the customview's frame. Here's a little Swift 3 Code

```
@IBOutlet var thinSpacer: UIBarButtonItem!

func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    let thinView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 22))
    self.thinSpacer.customView = thinView

    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressed(gestureRecognizer:)))
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    ...
}

func longPressed(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    guard gestureRecognizer.state == .began, let spacer = self.thinSpacer.customView else { return }
    let point = gestureRecognizer.location(ofTouch: 0, in: gestureRecognizer.view)
    if point.x < spacer.frame.origin.x {
        print("Long Press Success!")
    } else {
        print("Long Pressed Somewhere Else")
    }
}
```

Definitely not ideal, but easy enough for my use case. If you need a specify a long press on specific buttons in specific locations, it gets a little more annoying but you should be able to surround the buttons you need to detect the long press on with thin spacers and then just check that your point's X is between both of those spacers.

Comment: This works on iOS 11. An alternative to using the thin spacer (which unfortunately changes the alignment of the other items) is just comparing the touch location to a constant. This is quite easy if the button in question happens to be on either the left-most or right-most extreme, e.g. `if (point.x > self.view.frame.size.width-60)`.

Answer (score 1):

@voi1d's 2nd option answer is the most useful for those not wanting to rewrite all the functionality of `UIBarButtonItem`'s. I wrapped this in a category so that you can just do:

```
[myToolbar addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer toBarButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButton];
```

with a little error handling in case you are interested. NOTE: each time you add or remove items from the toolbar using `setItems`, you will have to re-add any gesture recognizers -- I guess UIToolbar recreates the holding UIViews every time you adjust the items array.

**UIToolbar+Gesture.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIToolbar (Gesture)

- (void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer toBarButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButton;

@end
```

**UIToolbar+Gesture.m**

```
#import "UIToolbar+Gesture.h"

@implementation UIToolbar (Gesture)

- (void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer toBarButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButton {
  NSUInteger index = 0;
  NSInteger savedTag = barButton.tag;

  barButton.tag = NSNotFound;
  for (UIBarButtonItem *anItem in [self items]) {
    if (anItem.enabled) {
      anItem.tag = index;
      index ++;
    }
  }
  if (NSNotFound != barButton.tag) {
    [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:barButton.tag] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
  }
  barButton.tag = savedTag;
}

@end
```

Comment: my use case if for a UIBarButtonItem in a navigation item... How should you code be adapted/used in such case?

Comment: Your implementation did not work for me (anymore), but thustin2121's did: - (void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer toBarButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButton {
    UIView *view = [barButton valueForKey:@"view"];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the best solution, but I am going to post a rather easy solution that worked for me.

I have created a simple extension for `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
fileprivate extension UIBarButtonItem {
    var view: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
    }
    func addGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        view?.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

After this, you can simply add your gesture recognizers to the items in your ViewController's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

func setupLongPressObservation() {
    let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
        target: self, action: #selector(self.didLongPressMyBarButtonItem(recognizer:)))
    myBarButtonItem.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}
```

Comment: Since IOS11 `value(forKey: "view")` will return nil. The only solution seems to be to implement a custom view. See also the answer of laxman khanal.

Answer (score 0):

@utopians answer in Swift 4.2

```
@objc func myAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem, forEvent event:UIEvent) {
    let longPressed:Bool = (event.allTouches?.first?.tapCount).map {$0 == 0} ?? false

    ... handle long press ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most Swift-friendly and least hacky way I came up with. Works in iOS 12.

**Swift 5**

```
var longPressTimer: Timer?

let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchDown), for: .touchDown)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUp), for: .touchUpInside)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchCancel), for: .touchCancel)
let undoBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

@objc func touchDown() {
    longPressTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(longPressed), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func touchUp() {
    if longPressTimer?.isValid == false { return } // Long press already activated
    longPressTimer?.invalidate()
    longPressTimer = nil
    // Do tap action
}

@objc func touchCancel() {
    longPressTimer?.invalidate()
    longPressTimer = nil
}

@objc func longPressed() {
    // Do long press action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ready for use `UIBarButtonItem` subclass:

```or-tag-here
@objc protocol BarButtonItemDelegate {
    func longPress(in barButtonItem: BarButtonItem)
}

class BarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    @IBOutlet weak var delegate: BarButtonItemDelegate?
    private let button = UIButton(type: .system)

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(longPress)
        )
        button.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = tintColor
        customView = button
    }

    override var action: Selector? {
        set {
            if let action = newValue {
                button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
            }
        }
        get { return nil }
    }

    @objc private func longPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .began {
            delegate?.longPress(in: self)
        }
    }
}
```