# How to detect longpress in BarButtonitem

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar. When a user clicks it, it pops to another viewController.
Now i want that when user long-press on that button (navigation bar button) I want to show a help message.
I want help to detect the onlick event and longpress event separately.

Comment: How did you added `BarButtonItem` to your `NavigationBar`?

Comment: Did you read this old thread ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655630/how-can-you-add-a-uigesturerecognizer-to-a-uibarbuttonitem-as-in-the-common-undo.  problem is that barButton are not UIButtons, so you need some workaround.

Comment: you can create custom navBar instead of default one, and handle tap actions by using tapGestures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I found that UIBarButton has not property like longpress so all I do is take a UIButton give it longpress gesture and add that UIButton in navigation bar as UIBarButtonItem.

I hope it will helpful for someone else who is facing same problem.

```
        let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        btn.backgroundColor = .green
        
        let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longpress))
        btn.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        
        let barbtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barbtn
```

thank you :)

Comment: Unfortunately doing so you can't use system buttons like the share action button. Look at the solution posted by The Tom. That's what is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

try this in view didload:

```swift
let back = UIImage(named: "header_backarrow")
let backView = UIImageView(image: back)
backView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissManual))
backView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backView)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should create a button and set `UITapGestureRecognizer` & `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your button**

```swift
// Create a button
let yourButton = UIButton()
yourButton.backgroundColor = .red
yourButton.setTitle("long press", for: .normal)

// Create a tap gesture recognizer
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap))

// Create a long gesture recognizer
let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(long))

// You can set minimum duration of the press action 
longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 3 //The default duration is 0.5 seconds.

// Add your gestures to button
yourButton.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
yourButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: yourButton)
```

```swift
@objc private func didTap() {
    print("Did Tap")
}

@objc private func long() {
    // You can show the help message in here
    print("Long press")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `viewDidAppear` of your view controller you can add this :

```
let gestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myCalledFunction))
(myUIBarButton.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView)?.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

This is difficult because UIBarButton doesn't really expose its view and so you cannot directly add a gestureRecognizer to it.

You can however get a reference to its view by using the `value(forKey:)` method and then play with it.

Do not do this in the `viewDidLoad` as it is necessary for the view to have already been created in order for this to work.

Comment: This is the Solution. Works also if setting it in viewWillAppear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers require implementing a `UIBarButtonItem(customView:)` to achieve this. However this can be implemented with any `UIBarButtonItem` instance without implementing your own gesture recognizer code.

An `@IBAction` can actually be passed a second parameter containing the `UIEvent` triggering the action. For example, instead of defining -

```
@objc func doSomething(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
}
```

We can define -

```
@objc func doSomething(sender: UIBarButtonItem, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    guard let touch = event.allTouches?.first else { return }
    
    if touch.tapCount == 1 {
        // Handle tap
    } else if touch.tapCount == 0 {
        // Handle long press
    }
}
```

**Source** : http://li366-68.members.linode.com/2016/09/07/detecting-long-presses-on-uibarbuttonitems.html

Comment: This is triggered only on button release. It is good to ignore the long press though.